# SQL Server CDC Latency

Tags: sql-server, debezium, cdc

SQL Server CDC is implemented by polling the transaction log by an specified interval.

We sepecified this interval to 1 second.

And to stream the data to sink, we adopt the debezium-kafka-connect bundle, in which we set the debezium polling interval to 1 second too.

Generally, the data synchronization latency is a little bit above 2 seconds.

I wonder if there is any possiblity to improve the latency even further.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The debezium polling interval can be further decreased, but I have no idea on how to decrease SQL Server CDC polling interval.

Comment: CDC is very much a "near real time" sort of system, emphasis on the near. I don't think it is a good fit if you are looking for immediate replication of data. For that you'd want to be raising application events. Of course, CDC has advantages that you don't get with application level events, like a guarantee that the data has in fact been persisted when you receive it, which is a guarantee you would otherwise have to code for yourself. In the end I think you just have to choose which matters more to your use case.

Comment: @allmhuran Firstly, we have to ensure data consistency, which is mentioned by you above. And secondly, the replication should not have much impact on online transaction. Thirdly, we want to minimize the latency. Lastly, we want less complexity.

Comment: You're sort of running into the problem described by the CAP theorem. In an environment of networked systems, you can either have consistency, or availability, but not both simultaneously. If you want absolute consistency in the data on different nodes (everybody sees the same data no matter what system they're in), then you can't have copies of the data replicated to other systems. If you want to have multiple copies of the data, then there is going to be some amount of latency. A couple of seconds latency is pretty good in an eventual consistency model (which is what you have).